# calling a function and callback not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a function that checks for Login and runs a few different things. Then I'm trying to call that function later in the page and have it execute another function after that's successful.  Maybe my structures not correct, although I've tried moving things around quite a bit and nothing seems to change anything or it breaks my code. Maybe this isn't the best way to this. Any ideas.

```
function callLogin(callback) {
  if (document.getElementById("userLoggedIn") === null) {
    $(".cover").fadeIn(200, function() {
      $(".sixPinInputContainer").fadeIn(200, function() {
        $('.sixPinInput').first().focus()
        $("#pageBody").css("overflow", "hidden");
        var failedAttempts = 0;
        var password = "";
        $('.sixPinInput').keyup(function(k) {
          //DATA ENTERED INTO FIELD
          if (this.value.length == this.maxLength) {
            password = password + this.value;
            $(this).next('.sixPinInput').focus();
          }
          //PRESSING DELETE
          if (k.keyCode == 8) {
            $(this).prev().val("").focus();
            password = password.slice(0, -1);
          }
          password = password.substring(0, 6);
          $(".pinIncorrectMessage").css("display", "none");
        });
        $("#f").keyup(function(callback) {
          if ($("#f").val().length > 0) {
            $.post("http://heber/QC/includes/pinInput/getUserInfo.php", {
              user: password
            }, function(data, status) {
              password = "";
              $(".sixPinInput").val("");
              $(data).each(function(index, value) {
                var firstName = value.firstName;
                var color1 = value.color1;
                var color2 = value.color2;
                var authorizationLevel = value.authorizationLevel;
                var something = value.something;

                //IF SUCCESSFUL LOGIN
                if (firstName) {
                  $(".cover").fadeOut(200);
                  $(".sixPinInputContainer").fadeOut(200);
                  $("#pageBody").css("overflow", "scroll");
                  $("#userName").html(firstName);
                  $("#pageBody").css("background", "radial-gradient(at top left," + color1 + "," + color2 + ")");
                  $("#userSession").html("<div id='userLoggedIn'></div>");
                  password = "";
                }
                //IF FAILED LOGIN
                if (!firstName) {
                  $(".pinIncorrectMessage").css("display", "block");
                  $(".sixPinInput").first().focus();
                  $(".sixPinInput").val("");
                  $("#userName").html(firstName);
                  $("#pageBody").css("background", "radial-gradient(at top left," + color1 + "," + color2 + ")");
                  password = "";
                  failedAttempts = failedAttempts + 1;
                  if (failedAttempts >= 3) {
                    alert("If you forgot your password Please have it reset, You have " + (6 - failedAttempts) + " more Attempts");
                  };
                  if (failedAttempts >= 6) {
                    $(".cover").css("background-color", "black").css("z-index", "2000").css("cursor", "none");
                  }
                }
              })
            })
          }
        })
      });
    });
  };
  callback();
};
```

Here's where I call the function and it runs the code inside before my login has completed.

```
callLogin(function() {
    $("#" + rowID).load("eventHandlersPHP/updateStart.php", {
    roomID: id }, function(data, status) {
       $("#notStartedCount").load("eventHandlersPHP/jobsNotStartedCount.php"); 
    });
});
```

Comment: well you call it not inside the Ajax calls....so of course it will run right away.

Comment: You have several `fadeIn`-calls with function parameters, but `callback();` seems to be placed outside of those functions. So `callback();` is executed as soon as the call to `fadeIn` itself completes, which will be really really quickly, because it does not wait for its function parameter to even start, let alone wait for it to finish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving the call of `callback` to the point where your request has completed :

```
//IF SUCCESSFUL LOGIN
if (firstName) {
    $(".cover").fadeOut(200);
    $(".sixPinInputContainer").fadeOut(200);
    $("#pageBody").css("overflow", "scroll");
    $("#userName").html(firstName);
    $("#pageBody").css("background","radial-gradient(at top left," + color1 + "," + color2 + ")");
    $("#userSession").html("<div id='userLoggedIn'></div>");
    password = "";

    callback();
}
```